# Does reviewing your application/checking application status improve your chances of getting a job?

Tags: applications, employer-relations

I remember a teacher in middle school once saying that when he got job applications he put them in a pile, waited a week, and if he hadn't heard from the applicant again, threw them away.  Though this always struck me as a bit foolish (introverts are often great problem solvers), I have never forgotten the advice.

That was, of course, before the advent of online job applications.  In this digital age, does the advice to contact potential employers still hold?  When the first step in a job application is to fill out a form online, how can you do that?  Does reviewing your application and/or checking application status improve your chances of getting a job?

Comment: Remember: There's a reason your teacher was teaching and not hiring.

Answer (score 6):

Ask the firm when you should follow-up with them.  They will tell you.  Many firms do not want to hear from you at all until after a certain, prescribed period has elapsed.

When the time comes, call them and say "I was asked to follow up today.  Is there any change in the status of my job application?"

Answer (score 0):

I would say that frequent checking of your aplication status would be more likley to hinder rather than help your application. The one thing above all you don't want to do is annoy the people who might be hiring. If I have 200 applicants, I don't want to field 200 phone calls a day asking how is the process going. If they are interested, you will be contacted. Often if you are not, they won't spend the time to contact you which is annoying but given the number of applications understandable.

If you are interviewed, then a follow up with a thank you note is appreciated and a call atfer two weeks or so would not be inappropriate (espeically if you havea nother job opportunity that you have to answer), but don't bug people. Follow up calls when you haven't been asked to an interview are generally disliked. You can call HR once to ensure they received the resume (espcially if it was not digitally submitted) but no more than that.